# Detect Gender ( Male or Female ) from Name

Tags: python, algorithm

I am developing an application in python in which I want to detect whether any name is typically a male or female name.

I did Google search on this, but could not find any algorithm/code by which I can do it. However I found a website which is doing the same thing pretty well: http://www.i-gender.com/

I was thinking to use their API in my application, but before that just wanted to how they are detecting the gender from name? Is it really possible to do it algorithmically? Please suggest some docs/links.

Here what I am trying:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import json
>>> req = urllib2.Request("http://www.i-gender.com/ai", "name=jhony")
>>> resp = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
>>> decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
>>> result = decoder.decode(resp)
>>> print result['gender']
male
>>> print result['confidence']
100
>>>
```

Comment: This is not directly related to programming, while I am sure there are ways to go about this problematically, the issue is not on a programming level.

Comment: I seriously doubt they're doing this algorithmically. They probably use a dictionary to look up names that are exclusively male or female, then use [probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) for names that can be either.

Comment: Of course it isn't reliable, don't you know the song "a boy named sue"? ;-)

Comment: You'd need some form of trainable system, like a neural net.  Then you'd need to feed it data, possibly US Census data could work.  This is a very complex task.

Comment: Read on Natural Language Processing, or as sr2222 suggested Neural Networks. (You will probably end up needing a combination of both).

Comment: I think, you need to compose a dictionary with all names and appropriate gender probabilities. If you want to guess gender for name which is not in the dictionary, you should train some guesser, like neural network.

Comment: Most commonly is a link or a dump of the national statistical database of gender and names. It should be public record of the amount of X of a certain name and what gender they are so go with that?

Comment: Don't. Just, don't. Seriously. Stop. Don't do this.

Comment: No matter how you choose to implement this, it will be very bad. Think of systems which try to remove swear words from names. All of the Prashits in the world are very disappointed.

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess they probably use a database, possibly supplemented by an algorithm to guess about names that aren't in the database.

There are quite a few names (e.g., "Pat") for which either gender is fairly common. If you look internationally, quite a few names that are generally attached to one gender in one country may be attached to the other gender in other countries, and may be relatively free of gender-attachment in still others.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments you want to read on Natural Language Processing, or as sr2222 suggested Neural Networks. (You will probably end up needing a combination of both). If iGender is actively trying to create an Artificial Intelligent Gender Prediction Tool, as they claim, they are using this as well.

There are many available, and a simple Google search will get you far.
I would recommend for Python: NLTK, and/or PyBrain.
NLTK has a (free) book and one of the chapters is actually about name/gender prediction.

In regards to their API, have you installed all the requirements?
What is the problem your running in? Looking at your code it seems to work fine to me.. ?

---

If you don't mind me asking, what are you trying to achieve? There might be easier / better and more reliable options available.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be hardpressed to find an algorithm to detect gender.

One thing you could do is create a dictionary with a name as a key, and a gender as a value.

Other things you will have to consider are names that can be for a boy or girl, and non-english names, these variables could factor into your `confidence`.